# tkinter.filedialog open file and savefile methods . How to choose?

Tags: python, tkinter, filedialog

tkinter.filedialog ...

asksaveasfile() vs asksaveasfilename()

askopenfile() vs askopenfilename()

when would I use one vs the other?

Comment: I am glad you asked this question. I did not even know there was a difference or even think to look for one until you asked. Lean something new every day :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`asksaveasfilename()` and `askopenfilename()` return only the path to the selected file as a `str` object. On the other hand, `askopenfile()` and `asksaveasfile()` return an actual file-like object (technically, an object of type `_io.TextIOWrapper`) which you can use to read from or write to later on. For instance:

```
with tkinter.filedialog.askopenfile() as f:
    contents = f.read()
    print(contents)
```

Comment: @PatrickDennis: `with open(tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()) as f: ...`